# Global Window allowedLateness

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In the gaming pipeline examples there is an example of a global/infite window that has an allowed lateness defined.

```
public PCollection<KV<String, Integer>> apply(PCollection<GameActionInfo> input) {
    return input.apply("LeaderboardUserGlobalWindow",
        Window.<GameActionInfo>into(new GlobalWindows())
            // Get periodic results every ten minutes.
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
                .plusDelayOf(TEN_MINUTES)))
            .accumulatingFiredPanes()
            **.withAllowedLateness(allowedLateness)**)
        // Extract and sum username/score pairs from the event data.
        .apply("ExtractUserScore", new ExtractAndSumScore("user"));
  }
```

Let us say the allowed Lateness is set to 36h.

Does this mean that there is an Window triggered every ten minutes than contains all the data from the beginning to those point minutes and each those of windows gets retriggered if any late data arrives?

E.g.

At after 30 minutes of processing time there would be windows:

```
A(10min)
B(20min)
C(30min)
```

If at minute 35 of processing time an message (X) arrives that has a event timestamp of minute 5, I would have the following outputs

```
old: A(10min)
old: B(20min)
old: C(30min)
new: A1(35min, equals all elements in A+X)
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your understanding is correct.

Also, any data later than 36hrs will be discarded.

Comment: Anil, thank you for your response. Is there any way for me to identify which type the output is then and especially for which period it is relevant? At the moment I write A,B,C and A1 to the same big query table. They all have the same window_timestamp which is the one from the unique window, so it doesn't help me and they all have a timing of EARLY and the index is just an increment which is not helping me either?

Comment: Michael, that is an interesting question. IIUC, is your question how to differentiate the elements fired for each trigger, since the window_timestamp is the same for them?

Comment: Yeah exactly that is my question. If there is no way to differentiate then allowed lateness for an infinite window is useless as you never now for which trigger the result set is?